# Dynamically Injecting Attribute to a Method

Tags: c#, unit-testing

During unit testing I need to decorate my methods with Test attributes as shown below:

```
[Test] 
 public class when_1_is_passed : specifications_for_prime_test
    {
        public void should_return_false()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1,1);
        }
    }
```

The [Test] attributes represents that a method is a test method. I want to get rid of the [Test] attribute. In 95% of the cases all the methods defined in the test suite will be test methods. The other 5% can be initialization code etc.

Anyway, now somehow I need to inject the TestAttribute to all of the methods dynamically. I have the following code but I don't see a way to inject attributes on a method.

```
public static void Configure<T>(T t)
        {
            var assemblyName = "TestSuite";
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);

            var assemblyTypes = assembly.GetTypes();

            foreach (var assemblyType in assemblyTypes)
            {
                if(assemblyType.BaseType == typeof(specifications_for_prime_test)) 
                {
                    // get all the methods from the class and inject the TestMethod attribute 

                    var methodInfos = assemblyType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly); 
                    foreach(var methodInfo in methodInfos)
                    {
                        // now attach the TestAttribute to the method
                    }
                }
            }

            var methodsInfo = t.GetType().GetMethods();  
        }
```

OR there maybe some hidden feature of the unit testing framework which allows the user to simply put the attribute on the class and all the methods inside that class becomes a test method.

Here is what the Tests looks like:

```
[TestFixture]
    public class specifications_for_prime_test
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void initialize()
        {
            UnitTestHelper.Configure(this); 
        }
    }

    public class when_1_is_passed : specifications_for_prime_test
    {
        public void should_return_false()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1,1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding the motivation for doing this.

Comment: I think I may be missing something, but would your [Test] methods not be in a [TestFixture] test class? If that's the case, why would you need to ever remove the test attributes?

Comment: The idea of doing this is to remove to manually adding the [Test] attribute. Once, all the methods will have the [Test] attribute they will be treated as Unit Tests.

Comment: @Russ Cam You are right the [Test] attributes will be in a class with the TestFixture attribute. My point is that all the methods inside the  class decorated with TestFixture] attribute are tests so why explicitly decorate them with the [Test] attribute.

Comment: I'm still not sure how that could be useful. When you're writing your unit tests, how labourious is it to put the attribute on whilst writing the test?

Comment: @Russ I agree that it is not that much work but if we can automate it it would be even better!

Comment: I just use a Resharper macro to create a test definition for me, including attribute, with a couple of keystrokes.

Comment: All methods in a TestFixture are not test methods.  The methods decorated with [Test] are the entry points used by the testing framework.  You may have many other methods in your class that are not meant to be accessed directly by the test harness.

Comment: @Rick, You are right! These can be initialization methods, tear down methods etc. Usually, I would put those methods in a different class, BaseUnitTest class. This is the reason I only have Test methods inside a class which is decorated with TestFixture attribute.

Comment: I do the same thing as womp with a snippet. You're working against the design of the library. There are other attributes that make the test methods behave differently; do you want to remove those too? Attributes are your friends. They make the implicit explicit. Spend five minutes creating a snippet or a macro and don't worry about it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you do not decorate the Test methods with the Test attribute, but instead, you prefix the name of the Test-methods with Test.

See [this](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=test&r=2.2.8).

NUnit should recognize it as a Test-method as well, without you having to decorate the method with `TestAttribute`
However, I've tested this with NUnit 2.4.7, and this doesn't seem to be true anymore.

Anyway, I do not see the reason why this bothers you ?  What is the problem with having a method decorated with a Test-Attribute ?  This just makes it explicit that it is a Test.
I like explicitness :)

Comment: I use MBUnit and I just tried it and it did not work. You are right it is not a big deal to decorate methods with [Test] attribute but I was looking for a way to remove it.

Comment: "Beginning with version 2.2.1, old style test cases ("Test....") are no longer recognized by default. **We recommend that you convert such test cases to use the TestAttribute.** Alternatively, you may specify a setting in the test config file to allow use of old style test cases by default." See http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=upgrade&r=2.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Can you make use of [`TypeDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171819.aspx)?

Comment: Seems like the TypeDescriptor can only be used to add attributes on class level.

Comment: Too bad. It seems to have PropertyDescriptor and EventDescriptor, but no MethodDescriptor. Odd. Looking at the problem from another angle, can you tell your unit testing framework which classes and methods are testable? If so, you could make your own list of methods and pass it in. Not sure if that is possible, but it would be nice :-)